# LIS3DH not working with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, accelerometer

I am new to LIS3DH and tried to interface it with Arduino Uno. I have made the circuit as follows-
LIS3DH    :    Arduino Uno
SCL       :    SCL (GPIO18)
SDA       :    SDA (GPIO19)
3.3v      :    3.3v
Gnd       :    Gnd

I used the example code from below link -
[sparkfun LIS3DH hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/lis3dh-hookup-guide/all)

Even though I tried to change the scl/sda pins to A4 and A5, I am not getting any results. All the time I am getting same values for all orientations.

Let me know if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/ if it finds any address in the bus

Comment: Hi, just to update, deleting the header file "SPI.h" makes it work. I don't know why but it is working. Also, same thing happened in esp8266 nodemcu.